# Semantic Zoom, zoomed in view items from API

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, semantic-zoom

I'm implementing the semantic zoom control in Windows 8.1 Xaml.  I have a list of top level category items.  When a user clicks one of those items, I'd like to load the zoomed in level items from an API.  Is this possible?  I've tried handling the click event of the zoomed out view Gridview, but there is no information about the item that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle the ItemClick event for GridView you must set ItemClickEnabled property to true.Otherwise , it won't trigger.

Comment: The question was not how to wire the item click event of a gridview.  The question is about semantic zoom.  Semantic zoom contains a zoomed in view and a zoomed out view. Items on both views are normally implemented statically.  This was asking how to implement the zoomed in view dynamically